# Scanning string into structure

Tags: c, string, file-io, structure

Inside the text file, the first number is number of albums, second is number of tracks associated with a single album, and the number infront of each track title is the character length of the title.

Right now I am having trouble scanning in the name of each individual title (without the number in front) into `char **tracks;` which is also part of an array of Structs

For example, `info[0].tracks[0]` should print out the string "Like an umbrella".

Example Text File:

```
1
17
16 Like an umbrella
...
15 Dynasty Warrior
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct album 
{
     int num_tracks;
     char **tracks;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int numbALBUMS=0, numbCharInTrack=0;
int i=0,j=0;

    FILE *albums;
    albums = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    fscanf(albums, "%d", &numbALBUMS);
    struct album *info = (struct album*)malloc(numbALBUMS * sizeof(struct album));

    for(i=0;i<numbALBUMS;i++){
        fscanf(albums, "%d", &info[i].num_tracks);
        info[i].tracks = malloc(sizeof(char*) * info[i].num_tracks);

            for(j=0;j<info[i].num_tracks;j++){
                fscanf(albums, "%d", &numbCharInTrack);
                info[i].tracks[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * numbCharInTrack);

                //NEED HELP HERE

            }
    }


fclose(albums);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are correct, I read an extra `*` into the mix. Done.

Comment: the return code(s) from fscanf() and malloc() and fopen() need to be checked for success before trying to use the related data.

Comment: all those memory allocations need to be passed to free() before exiting the program to avoid memory leaks/resource losses

Comment: at //NEED HELP HERE, simply use getchar() to step by the intervening space, then use fgets() to read the actual title into the allocated memory.  this will get everything until the new line and append a '\0' to terminate the string, (so the allocation needs to be 1 larger than the read in number of characters to allow for the trailing '\0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
fscanf(albums, "%d", &numbCharInTrack);
info[i].tracks[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (numbCharInTrack+1));//+1 for NUL, sizeof(char) is always 1(by standard)
fscanf(albums, " %[^\n]", info[i].tracks[j]);//Space to skip the previous space
```

Comment: Are you sure about using the `dot` operator for element access after declaring a pointer to struct with `struct album *info`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin type of `info` is  `struct album *info`. So `info[i].XXX`. If you have a pointer to the array representation it is an entity rather than a pointer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin E.g `int a[] = {1,2,3};int *p = a;` , type of `p[i]` is `int`, not pointer.